# Alter the schema of Hive table

Tags: hive, hbase, impala, metastore

I want to alter the table created in Hive which is mapped to HBase fields. Recently i have included few more column into HBase and thus would lik to add those fields into Hive as well.

for creation i used:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1(rowKey STRING,a STRING,b STRING) 
 STORED BY  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
 ('hbase.columns.mapping' = ':key,cf:address,cf:name') 
 TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name' = 'test');
```

now i want to add one more column in hive tables test1 which should be mapped to hbase but i don't find any way to do this. Pleas help Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use external table, the easiest way is drop and create it again.

`drop table test1;`

and

`create external table  test1 {...};`

Comment: I am not looking for easiest way.